# Cant write to ntfs drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

HI i have a NTFS drive insalled on my machine runing ubuntu 20.04 and on the file explorer if i go to other locations, i can see the drive and can click and view the files inside it.

HOwever, when i try to copy new files into it, it says it cant and i dont have permisison to?

I then right clicked the ntfs drive and when to its properties and then onto the permision option and ticked everything to allow me, owner and "others" to read/write on it but it still wont let me copy files into it?

ANy suggestions?

Comment: Have you used Windows to connect to that drive? In that case, maybe Windows uses 'Fast Startup', which is a kind of semi-hibernation. Thiis leaves the file systems connected at 'shutdown' with a 'dirty' flag, and linux stays away from writing to it. A work-around is to reboot Windows instead of shutting it down, and then, at the UEFI/BIOS stage of the boot process *poweroff*. A solution is to turn off Fast Startup is Windows. -- But there might also be other problems. Please keep us informed about the progress of your issue.

Comment: i have a dual boot setup, 3 hdds, one with windows OS, one with ubuntu and the other is just a data drive formated in ntfs(the one i am trying to access)

Comment: Yes, I see. Do you know if your Windows system is using Fast Startup (it is the standard setting in Windows 10)?

Comment: it probably is, i am not sure. how do i check?

Comment: Search the internet for `turn off fast startup` -- for example [this link](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10)

Comment: No mark it doesnt, the ntfsfix does not work. i will try rebooting to windows and disabling the fast start

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there is no problem mounting a NTFS disk for read and write in Ubuntu. To make it effortless you can do like this, it's quite a few steps:

1. Find out what the UUID is for the NTFS disk. `blkid -l` will give you a list like:

   ```
   /dev/sda1: UUID="9272-FF30" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="ed4acd72-8320-45db-b661-1976189c1da5"
   /dev/sda2: UUID="f9a58a66-94ea-4ab7-a214-019912085453" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0852f2b3-cf16-4c9e-9886-82e0b35c81cf"
   /dev/sda3: UUID="558179d8-c6c3-41e3-9cd7-08da53b68df8" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0ad691be-1d64-4ba1-bf70-8682818aa6b8"
   /dev/sdb1: UUID="BC2E8B1A2E8ACD38" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="6dbd7f38-fe9e-4eb5-9769-2803188075b8"
   ```

   If you get more than one NTFS partition you can find which one by looking further
   with `lsblk` and/or `blkid -l` but for now I assume that we found the NTFS
   partition above.
2. Make sure you have the NTFS driver installed

   ```
   dpkg -l | grep ntfs
   ```

   which, if installed, will give an output something like this:

   ```
   ii  libntfs-3g883   1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1   amd64  read/write NTFS driver for FUSE (runtime library)
   ii  ntfs-3g         1:2017.3.23AR.3-3ubuntu1   amd64  read/write NTFS driver for FUSE
   ```
3. If you don't get any output with the `dpkg` command then install the NTFS driver
   with:

   ```
   sudo apt install ntfs-3g
   ```

   which will install the NTFS runtime as well
4. Make a mount point for the drive e.g. `sudo mkdir /mnt/ntfs` (name it whatever
   you like, this is just an example) and make it yours with
   `sudo chown jonathan:jonathan /mnt/ntfs` (if jonathan is your user name)
5. Edit `/etc/fstab` and add the line (with the UUID you found):

   ```
   UUID=BC2E8B1A2E8ACD38 /mnt/ntfs ntfs-3g   defaults,nls=utf8,umask=027,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
   ```

   where the masks give you read/write for everything on the drive so be careful if
   this is your Windows installation disk. Also note that I assume that you have
   user and group ID 1000. If not enter your values. If you don't know, find out
   with `id -u jonathan` and `id -g jonathan`
6. Mount it with `sudo mount /mnt/ntfs`. It will automatically mount at every
   start. If you still have problems with write permissions you have to turn
   off fast startup in Windows as suggested by @sudodus in the comments above.